# C++: Unexpected performance boost using greater comparator

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I was submitting my solution for an algorithm problem to an online grader system, and at first, the solution exceeded the time limit, it took around ~4s.

I was completely sure that the complexity was the correct one, so I was started optimizing parts of my code and nothing great happened, till I noticed something really strange.

I was using a priority queue of pairs and I chose to implement my own Comparator

```
struct Comparator{  
  bool operator()(pair<int, int> node1, pair<int, int> node2){  
      return node1.second < node2.second;  
  }  
};
```

When I changed that to the `greater` comparator of the `<algorithm>` library, there was a significant performance boost; the solution passed and it only took ~300ms.

Extra info: I am using the priority queue for implementing a "tweaked"  version of Dijkstra. The queue declaration was:  `priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, Comparator> q;` and I changed that to: 
`priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, greater<pair<int, int>>> q;`.

I am really curious why this happened. For me, it is pretty straightforward what a comparator should do, and I can't think of any more efficient way of doing that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], presumably your use of `std::greater` doesn't have equivalent behaviour to your comparator

Comment: Especially since your comparator uses less than

Comment: the custom comparator is taking arguments by value instead of const reference, so it will create unnecessary copies for each comparison. This might be the issue

Comment: @AlanBirtles  I updated the question to make clear the way I am using the priority queue and what for. I don't see any point in sharing more implementation details, because the rest of them don't regard the queue itself, but if you still believe that there is something missing from my question, feel free to ask.

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri I checked the behavior locally using time with the compiled with optimizations file and I saw the same results, so probably it's not that

Comment: @NishantSingh sounds reasonable.

Comment: Your custom comparator is functionally equivalent to `std::less`, not to `std::greater`. How does your program fare with `std::less`?

Comment: without a [mcve] we can't tell whether your comparison being completely different to std::greater (it uses less than on second whereas std::greater uses greater than on first then second) is a significant factor

Comment: My first guess is that your comparator passes data by value and compiler might have not optimized it

Answer (score 3):

There are several things that can cause performance difference :

```
struct Comparator{  
  bool operator()(pair<int, int> node1, pair<int, int> node2){  
      return node1.second < node2.second;  
  }  
};
```

vs. `std::greater`

1. The custom comparator gets objects by value and `std::greater` gets them by reference. I doubt that this will have an effect of more than 10%.
2. `std::greater` compares `node2.first < node1.first` if `node2.first != node1.first` otherwise it is `node2.second < node1.second`. The comparison is completely different than that of `Comparator`, which compares `node1.second < node2.second`.

   Since the comparison results are different, your code goes through completely different paths. Going through different paths can have a profound impact on the big O complexity and performance. This is most likely the real cause for the difference.

For a reference of `std::greater` look at what [`std::pair::operator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) is doing:

> If `lhs.first<rhs.first`, returns `true`. Otherwise, if `rhs.first<lhs.first`, returns `false`. Otherwise, if `lhs.second<rhs.second`, returns `true`. Otherwise, returns `false`.